# How to open Terminal with last tabs open?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When you are using Terminal in Mac there is option to open last opened tabs when you launch Terminal. 
Is there an option available on Ubnutu's (12.10) Terminal?

This is helpful when you have lot of tabs open and want each tab back with some history and  some specific directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the use of tmux or screen for this. They are what are called terminal multiplexers and allow you to run many terminals with different tab and pane configurations.  They both have powerful configuration files that allow you to specify tab and pane configuration on startup.